# Making anagram from two words in php

Tags: php, automation, anagram

For example: a)First we make a word from two parts

```
$word1 = 'bel';
$word2 = 'grade';
$newWord = 'belgrade';
```

b)now I should make anagram from this word where letters from two words are alternating one by one' `belgrade -> bgerlade`

i did this with 2 for loops, but i need automatised solution :

```
 $arr = ['b','e','o', ''];
     $arr1 = ['g', 'r', 'a', 'd'];

    for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
    { for($i = 0; $i<count($arr1); $i++)     
{
         if ($i % 2 == 0)
         {
         echo $arr[$i] . $arr1[$i] . PHP_EOL;
         }     
    if ($i % 2 != 0)
        {
            echo $arr[$i] . $arr1[$i] . PHP_EOL;
         }

     }
     }
```

Comment: the example you cite alternates the first few characters but both end with `ade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code starts with the two strings.  Then it uses `str_split()` to split them into single character arrays.

Then it loops while there is some content left and adds 1 char from the first array(if any) and the same with the second array.  Using `array_shift()` each time gets the first element off the array and so both returns the next character as well as removing it from the array.  Adding it to the output using `.=` ...

```
$word1 = 'bel';
$word2 = 'grade';

$arr1 = str_split($word1);
$arr2 = str_split($word2);

$output = '';
while( count($arr1)  || count($arr2) )  {
    if ( count($arr1) ) {
        $output .= array_shift($arr1);
    }
    if ( count($arr2) ) {
        $output .= array_shift($arr2);
    }
}
echo $output;
```